# Сравнить текст из колонок таблицы с пришедшим результатом

Tags: jquery, php, html, mysql

Всем привет.

Такой вопрос.
Есть таблица вида

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="label">Значение 1</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="arr[1]" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="label">Значение 50</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="arr[50]" value="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="label">Значение 2</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="arr[2]" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вообще значений может быть в редких случаях и 30 и 50...

ajax запрос возвращает мне массив

```
Array
(
    [values] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [vName] => Значение 50
            [vValue] =>
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [vName] => Значение 768
            [vValue] =>
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [vName] => Значение 110
            [vValue] =>
        )
    )
)
```

Мне нужно в success пройтись по массиву и сравнить каждый vName с тем, что в дивах с классом label.

Если vName нет в таблице, то выполняем действие, если есть, то нужно заменить value в соответствующем input

Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: По всей видимости Ajax отдает вам данные не в JSON, что не очень удобно для обработки в JS. Сделайте на стороне сервера echo json_encode($array); И после в Success, прокрутите переменную result примерно так result.values.vName[i]

Comment: Нет. возвращает в json. я просто привел массив данных для примера, чтобы понятно было.
проблем в этом нет. я просто не знаю тонкостей работы с js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить [такое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QeVE4/1/). Может не идеальное, но пока - это первое, что пришло в голову. В примере я подсвечиваю элементы, а вы можете выполнять с ними свои действия.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Разобрался.